# Cocos2d with Swift Detecting Collisions Between The Same Type of Sprite

Tags: iphone, swift, cocos2d-iphone

I am having a problem with a game I am currently developing in Swift.  I have blocks that turn static upon hitting each other or the ground and my hero sprite cant go through them so instead he just goes under them when enough force is applied.  Obviously I dont want this and simply want him to not be able to move any more left or right when he comes in contact with a block from the right or left side.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your hero moving is an action you programmed, you can use .stopAllActions() to make him stop moving when he collides with one of the blocks.